# Cannot connect a containerized Spring WebFlux application to remote MongoDB server

Tags: spring, mongodb, docker, kotlin, spring-webflux

I am using Spring WebFlux to create a Reactive REST API. I have a Kubernetes cluster provisioned on IBM Cloud and a MongoDB database hosted there. For simplicity, let's say the host is `1.2.3.4` and the port `12345`. The application connects to the MongoDB server when not containerized with Docker. However when I containerize it and try to run the app from the container:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM amd64/gradle:6.6.1-jdk11
COPY build/libs/some.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "-Dspring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://USERNAME:PASSWORD@http://1.2.3.4:12345/db-name?authSource=admin", "./app.jar"]
```

**Build**

```
docker build . -t myapp
```

**Run**

```
docker run -p 80:8080 myapp
```

I get the following **MongoSocketOpenException**:

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.AsynchronousSocketChannelStream$OpenCompletionHandler.failed(AsynchronousSocketChannelStream.java:116) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar!/:na]
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:129) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Invoker$2.run(Invoker.java:219) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl$1.run(AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl.java:112) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:252) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.finish(UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:198) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.onEvent(UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:213) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.EPollPort$EventHandlerTask.run(EPollPort.java:306) ~[na:na]
... 1 common frames omitted
```

Things I have tried:

1. Added code to exclude **MongoAutoConfiguration**, **MongoReactiveAutoConfiguration**, and **MongoDataAutoConfiguration** to **MyApplication.kt**.

   ```
   @SpringBootApplication(exclude = [
       MongoAutoConfiguration::class,
       MongoReactiveAutoConfiguration::class,
       MongoDataAutoConfiguration::class
   ]
   class MyApplication

   fun main(args: Array<String>) {
       runApplication<MyApplication>(*args)
   }
   ```
2. Hardcoded the application URI in my MongoConfig class

   ```
   @Configuration
   @EnableReactiveMongoRepositories(basePackageClasses = [SomeRepository::class])
   class MongoConfiguration : AbstractReactiveMongoConfiguration() {

       override fun getDatabaseName(): String = "db-name"

       override fun reactiveMongoClient(): MongoClient = mongoClient()

       @Bean
       fun mongoClient(): MongoClient = MongoClients.create("mongodb://USERNAME:PASSWORD@1.2.3.4:12345/${databaseName}?authSource=admin")

       @Bean
       override fun reactiveMongoTemplate(@Qualifier("reactiveMongoDatabaseFactory") databaseFactory: ReactiveMongoDatabaseFactory, mongoConverter: MappingMongoConverter): ReactiveMongoTemplate = ReactiveMongoTemplate(mongoClient(), databaseName)
   }
   ```

I am mostly building this to learn some new skills, normally I am pretty good at figuring out the issue, but I am stuck here. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: have you tried axposing the database port outside the container. Feels it would be hard to connect to a database if it is not exposed....

Comment: the same problem here, could you fix it?